# Modified server.properties and now I can't create topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I installed kafka on my machine using brew.

```
brew install kafka
```

I opened the following file

```
/usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

By default kafka brokers run on 9092. but in my case this port is already taken by elastic search.

So I made the following entry in this file

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://abhisheks-mini:9093
```

Now i restarted kafka using `brew services restart kafka`

but now if I try to do

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic test
```

I get an error

```
Error while executing topic command : replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
[2017-09-30 12:39:18,076] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

I think this is because I changed the port and the utility does not know about the new port.

Comment: The broker is not running. Take a look at jps output to make sure it's running. You can also look in the Kafka logs to see why it may have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently `kafka-topics.sh` only talks to zookeeper and according to ZK you don't have a broker running.

I suggest you check the broker logs (`/usr/local/var/log/kafka`) to see why it failed starting.

Also if you only want to change the port, you don't need to provide a hostname/ip, you just need:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
```

Comment: you gave the right tip. Once i modify server.properties we have to restart Zookerper. Otherwise Zookeeper still has the old port. So in my case the broker was running but zookeeper did not know about the new port.

So I just restarted zookeeper and now the new port got registered. and I am able to create topics.